# Getting NotImplementedError file fetching table data from pdf using python pdftables

Tags: python, pdf

I am using Python pdftables to fetch table data from pdf and i followed the instructions as give in git

https://github.com/drj11/pdftables

but when i run the code

```
filepath = 'tests.pdf'
fileobj = open(filepath,'rb')
from pdftables.pdf_document import PDFDocument
doc = PDFDocument.from_fileobj(fileobj)
```

i get error like this

```
       File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
       File "pdftables/pdf_document.py", line 53, in from_fileobj
       raise NotImplementedError
```

can any anyone help me out in this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [file](https://github.com/drj11/pdftables/blob/dev/pdftables/pdf_document.py#L49) implementing the `from_fileobj` function you can see the following comment:

```
# TODO(pwaller): For now, put fh into a temporary file and call
# .from_path. Future: when we have a working stream input function for
# poppler, use that.
```

If I understand it correctly you should instead use the `from_path` function as `from_fileobj` is not implemented yet. This is easy with your current code:

```
filepath = 'tests.pdf'
from pdftables.pdf_document import PDFDocument
doc = PDFDocument.from_path(filepath)
```